# Why not giving more preferences to searching at Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, search

Stack Overflow is becoming the largest repository in technical discussion as well nontechnical. We have lots of separate sites for different things. Why do not Stack Overflow provide a common search place to search questions from the Stack Overflow database? By the way, we can reduce the number of repeated questions.

**Some search concepts to be implemented:**

> 1. We have searching options for each site separately, but the user do not know
>      where to search for specific question. So, they simply
>      post a new question.
> 2. Rather than having a search form at the site corner, (seen from the user's perspective) Stack Overflow can provide an appealing search page where users can start. A user would then not need to wait for an answer in case he/she already found an answer
>      surfing the discussions.
> 3. Also to be considered, the user can have an option of choosing a specific
>      category like platform or sites.
> 4. After the searching process is completed, you can sort the results
>      based on date, vote, or max answered
>      and so on.

I do not know my suggestion are right or not. Just wanted to share.
People having similar thoughts please proceed to write.

I hope see a master search engine for our Stack Overflow site. :)

Answer (score 3):

> I hope see a master search engine for our Stack Overflow site. :)

Wish already granted

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/

Try it out like so

https://stackexchange.com/search?q=the+center+cannot+hold